# Jmeter - CSV files - sending values from global csv to local csv

Tags: csv, groovy, jmeter, beanshell

I'm having a `globaluser.csv` with columns

```
glbluserid;xxxx
glblpassword;yyyyy
```

I store the global variables in `props.put(key, value)` as a first step

There is a `localuser.csv`

```
userid;password
aaaaa;bbbbbb
```

is it possible to send the values to replace the local with the global

is it possible to configure the `localuser.csv` in anyone of the possibilites?

```
userid;password
${glbluserid};${glblpassword}
${__P(glbluserid)};${__P(glblpassword)}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO @Vish, Your question is not that clear, can you please add context that is what is the problem you had and why you need two csv files and then why you need to replace the values ?

Comment: @4m01  the context is, test cases can be deployed in multiple environments where the input test data may not be similar. Hence I wanted to use a global csv file which can be configured on the fly depending on the environments and I don't have to modify each csv. Whereas, I would replace the corresponding global csv variable as mentioned in the example. So, the test cases can be modified quickly and can be scaled to be used with different test data inputs.